Kong blocks all IPs when rate-limiting plugin is added
I have setup an API-Gateway with kong and below is my kong.yml file.
_format_version: "2.1"
_transform: true

services:
  - name: auth-service
    url: http://xxxxxxxxxxx
    routes:
      - name: auth-routes
        paths:
          - /auth

  - name: audit-service
    url: http://xxxxxxxxxxx
    routes:
      - name: audit-routes
        paths:
          - /audits

plugins:
  - name: rate-limiting
    service: auth-service
    config:
      minute: 100
      hour: 1000
      day: 10000

  - name: rate-limiting
    service: audit-service
    config:
      minute: 100
      hour: 1000
      day: 10000

As you can see in my other server, I have couple of services running and kong handles the traffic according to the rotes.
The problem is, when the ratelimit is reached, kong blocks all IPs. Not just attacking IP. I tested this by running a K6 with a droplet and while it's running, I tried calling the API gateway from my PC and I got the message saying "rate-limit reached"
Any idea how to fix this ? Thanks!

According to the documentation, the IP is determined from headers passed into the requests : https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/rate-limiting/#limit-by-ip-address
Is there any proxy, firewall or load balancer in front of your API gateway that could possibly always set the same IP into those headers, which would lead the plugin to think that all the requests come from the same IP address ?

Thank you for the answer, your answer made me thinking that, yes I have setup a domain name for the APIgateway and I use nginx to map the domain name to IP_ADDRESS:PORT. So, In my k6 test, I replaced the domain name with IP_ADRESS:PORT. And then ran it again and it didnt block other IPs this time. Thanks again.

Make sure you preserve client IP address:
https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/guides/security/client-ip/
Cloudfront and Firewalls on the way to gateway may replace Host IP with their own and pass client IP in another header like X-Forwarded-For, you should configure your Kong to copy real IP.
